# Subgraph without "holes"

Tags: graph-theory, definition

does everyone know, if there already exists a definition of subgraphs, which do not contain a "hole"?

EDITED: That means: I presuppose a planar embedding of a graph G and I want to find a connected subgraph G', so that the subgraph do not surrounds any other node of the graph G \ G' in the given embedding. So it is a kind of "convex" subgraph. For example, if G' is cycle-free it would be such a subgraph.

Thanks a lot!
Benjamin

Comment: A planar graph has many different embeddings in the plane, so I think you should start with a "plane graph" (= a planar graph with a given embedding), and then you'll need to talk about subgraphs with respect to this embedding.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course you are right.